# Textarea scrollbar doesn't disappear despite width:0;

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

No scrollbar in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE, it doesn't disappear although the element width is 0:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Textarea Scrollbar</title>
    <style>
        textarea {
            height: 200px;
            width: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="textarea">
        Hello, world!
        ...
    </textarea>
    <input type="text" value="0" id="input" oninput="resize();">
    <script>
        function resize() {
            document.getElementById('textarea').style.width = document.getElementById('input').value + 'px';
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vJK5W/)**</kbd>

What's the reason? What's a cross-browser solution so the textarea behaves like in Chrome?

Comment: What's the situation you're trying to resolve? Why would you have a text area set to 0px?

Comment: The textarea width changes programmatically and the user might set any width size value, including 0.

Comment: In that case, like Shakesy says, could you set the `display` or `overflow` properties of the text area?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to scroll inside your textarea?

Comment: @ W.D.: Like I said it should behave like Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow:hidden;` in the css for the text area attributed ID

Comment: It completely removes the scrollbar, even if you change its width to a number larger than 0. It should behave like Chrome.

Comment: So use some jQuery, if <1 then overflow hidden, if >0 then overflow:automatic.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wQG7N/8/)**</kbd>

**Javascript**

```
//this function attaches eventListener to the element and it is compatible with legacy browsers as well
function attach(element,listener,ev,tf){

    if(element.attachEvent) {

        //support for older IE (IE7 inclusive)
        element.attachEvent("on"+listener,ev);

        }else{

        //modern browsers
        element.addEventListener(listener,ev,tf);

        }

    }

var newInterval; //we use this to set interval and check say every 200 milliseconds
                 //whether the *height* of our *textarea* has changed and if it has
                 //than we set its *overflow* to *auto*, so the *scrollbar* will be
                 //visible, but when the *height* is *less or equal to 200* we set
                 //its *overflow* to *hidden*, so the *scrollbar* isn't visible! 

var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

var input = document.getElementById('input');

//here we check if the value of our input element has changed than we change the width of our textarea 
attach(input,'input',function(){

textarea.style.width = input.value + 'px';

},false);


//when our textarea recieves focus (is clicked on) we start running the interval and
//check every 200 milliseconds if the height of the textarea is equal or greater than
//200px we set its overflow to auto so the scrollbar becomes visible, and when the
//height is equal or less than 200px we set our textareas overflow to hidden, so no
//scrollbar is visible

attach(textarea,'focus',function(){

 newInterval = setInterval(function(){

    height = textarea.scrollHeight;

        if(height>=200){

            textarea.style.overflow = 'auto'

        }else textarea.style.overflow = 'hidden';

    },200);

},false);

//here we clear our interval, as our textarea has lost focus
// and there is no need to further run our interval  
attach(textarea,'blur',function(){ clearInterval(newInterval); },false);
```

**HTML**

```
  <textarea id="textarea">
        Hello, world!
        ...
  </textarea>
  <input type="text" value="0" id="input" oninput="resize();">
```

**CSS**

```
textarea{

    height: 200px;
    width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I need to work on it to understand what you have done on your code. A different quick question, please: the word `DEMO` in your post looks different than mine. How did you do it?

Comment: @Hermes, I'm currently editing my post, will explain everything, but is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Thanks again!

Comment: He used `<kbd>Demo</kbd>`.

Comment: Like @Axel has said, I used <kbd>**[Text](link goes here)**</kbd>

Comment: Your code seems to be working well. However, Shakesy's approach seems simpler:[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vJK5W/2/).

Comment: It's up to you, which approach you will choose.

Comment: One more thing: the scrollbar in your demo only appears if you focus on the textarea, which is different from Chrome's behavior.